# Android studio 3.1 aidl is missing

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I just updated Android studio to version 3.1 few days ago. I am getting this error in `Build` tab AIDL is missing.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing from '.../sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/aidl'
```

Here is the complete console error I am getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing from '/Users/user_name/Documents/sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/aidl'
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.compileAllAidlFiles(AndroidBuilder.java:963)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AidlCompile.compileAllFiles(AidlCompile.java:132)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AidlCompile.doFullTaskAction(AidlCompile.java:188)
    ... 48 more
```

I have searched for this issue for specific Android Studio 3.1 but not found any solution yet.

Screen shot attached below

[image]

Comment: aidl is missing have you place the aidl file in application?

Comment: @AmjadKhan No there is no aidl file in my application. I just created a new Project and getting this error in Build.

Comment: @Zubairkhan Have you update your `build-tools` version

Comment: Yes its already updated

Comment: can you please add your gradle code

Comment: whats the output of `ls -l /Users/user_name/Documents/sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/aidl` ?

Comment: @pskink `No such file or directory`

Comment: so you have the answer for your question

Comment: I understand this thing but my question is why its giving me this error in previous Android Studio version 3.0.1 same sdk path and same build tools but never got this error.

Comment: whats the output of `ls -l /Users/user_name/Documents/sdk/build-tools/` then? dont you think that instead of `user_name` should be something else?

Comment: @pskink `total 0
drwxr-xr-x  38 user_name  staff  1216 Mar 27 10:20 26.0.3
drwxr-xr-x  39 user_name  staff  1248 Mar 27 10:20 27.0.3`

Comment: and `ls -l /Users/user_name/Documents/sdk/build-tools/27.0.3` ? do you have 30 files inside?

Comment: @pskink I got the hint from you. Silly me! got my answer. See my answer below. Thanks to you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer to my question. Actually I am new macbook user and shifted all my stuff from windows Laptop to this mac.

Silly me I also copied the `sdk` folder from laptop and set as sdk path. Aidl is missing because my build-tools folder has aidl `.exe` files which is surely not for macbook.

Thanks to `pskink` for the hints in comments. Really appreciated!

**EDIT**
Do not ever copy sdk from windows laptop to mac. Always use own mac's version sdk that comes along with android studio.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the versions of SDK, Build Tools and Gradle Plugins doesn't match.

This will be fixed if you use the latest versions of gradle plugins are placed in the project build.gradle, and the other versions are on the build.gradle of the module.